# Why voltage drops when I short a battery?

Tags: voltage, batteries

When I short an AA battery, I have observed that it's voltage drops a couple hundred millivolts and when I break the short, its voltage starts to "replenish" at a decreasing speed.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: What type of battery is it, alkaline, zinc/carbon, or some other chemistry? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Don't forget that shorting a battery is never good.It can easily damage it and you may witness an explosion in extreme cases,especially if it's of the Li-On type.Mainly because the internal resistance is not made to stand such high currents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, if you are truly shorting the battery, then its voltage will be 0 by definition.

It seems you are talking about the battery voltage shortly after abuse, like shorting.  Batteries work on chemical reactions, which don't happen instantaneously.  During heavy load, like being shorted, the battery is pumping charge around as much as it possibly can.  Internally, charge is moved around by ions physically moving thru some electrolyte.  Under heavy load, various things can happen to get in the way of efficient battery operation.  Some of these things are permanent, but others can recover after some time for things to diffuse around inside the battery.  This is why the open circuit voltage will be lower immediately after abuse, but will usually recover somewhat over time after that.

If you are asking why the voltage of a battery goes down with load, then the answer is in part internal resistance.  A very simplistic model of a battery is a fixed voltage source with a resistance in series, also known as a Thevenin source.  Even if the voltage source remains at the same level, the terminal voltage will go down with current since the drop across the resistance goes up with current.

There are also again chemical affects, so the voltage source doesn't stay fixed either.  As the battery ages, both the voltage source will go down and the internal resistance will go up.

Batteries are complicated.

Comment: Actually I have found this [answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/52204/58844) of yours. In it, you have written: "That's right in theory, but in reality the internal voltage source will drop due to some chemical effects at high current. It will also drop rapidly over time, so if you do this, you have to take the measurement quickly." That's precisely what I am wondering: What are those chemical effects that cause a rapid decrease in voltage in high currents? Where should I look for this info?

Comment: @Utku: I don't know, go ask a chemist.

Answer (score 3):

> When I short an AA battery, I have observed that it's voltage drops a
>   couple hundred millivolts

If you short a battery it produces zero volts at the terminals. If instead you place a heavy load on the battery, it will produce a significantly lower terminal voltage because, you cannot expect a battery to be able to supply infinite current.

Every real and practical voltage source has internal series resistance (also a bit of inductance too). It is the internal resistance that limits the short circuit supply current. On any load this internal resistance forms a potential divider with the load resistance and the terminal voltage will drop.

Regarding the voltage "slowly" returning to its full value following a short circuit, it's a chemical process in the battery and shorting it out, causes an overload to that chemical process and it takes time to recover.

[Wiki article - recovery effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recovery_effect)